# Ternary association with same table

Tags: sql, sequelize.js

I would like to make 2 tables and setup associations between them to have something that looks like this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFjCP.png

I'm not really sure but it looks like a ternary association where 2 columns are from the same table. Both `player1` and `player2` are of type `User`.

I tried something like this but I'm really not sure this is the way to go.

```js
const User = sequelize.define('User', { id: DataTypes.STRING })
const Battle = sequelize.define('Battle', { id: DataTypes.STRING })
const UserBattleParticipation = sequelize.define('UserBattleParticipation', {
  battleId: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    primaryKey: true,
    allowNull: false,
    references: {
      model: Battle,
      key: 'id'
    }
   },
  player1: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    primaryKey: true,
    allowNull: false,
    references: {
      model: User,
      key: 'id'
    } 
  },
  player2: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    primaryKey: true,
    allowNull: false,
    references: {
      model: User,
      key: 'id'
    }
  },
  additional: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  }
})

Battle.belongsToMany(User, { as: 'Participant', through:UserBattleParticipation, foreignKey: { name: 'battleId', allowNull: false} });
User.belongsToMany(Battle, { as: 'Attacker', through:UserBattleParticipation, foreignKey: { name: 'player1', allowNull: false } });
User.belongsToMany(Battle, { as: 'Target', through: UserBattleParticipation, foreignKey: { name: 'player2', allowNull: false } });
```

Comment: After I looked your association diagram I should ask you: Why do you use additional table about a battle? WIll it be a situation when you have two different records in `UserBattleParticipation` with the same `battleId` but with direefetnt players' ids?

Comment: @Anatoly Thanks for taking the time to look at this. Yes, `UserBattleParticipation` can have the same `battleId` but with different player id's. Basically, a battle is composed of hundred of participants: player1 attacks player2, one of the two is KO player3 attack the player that is still alive, etc...That's why I though the PK of `battleId,player1,player2` would be ok.
I also forgot to add it but `Battle` will have additinal column like `winner`, that also reference a `User`.

Comment: Also correct a name for `Battle` model

Comment: My bad, that was a copy paste from the line above.

Answer (score 0):

1. I suppose you turned upside down meanings of concrete associations:

```
// If you want to get a list of attackers in a certain battle you should define such association:
// I recommend to use aliases in plural because it's many-to-`many`
Battle.belongsToMany(User, { as: 'Attackers', through:UserBattleParticipation, foreignKey: { name: 'battleId', allowNull: false }, otherKey: { name: 'player1', allowNull: false } });

// If you want to get a list of battle where a user was as an attacker you should define such association:
User.belongsToMany(Battle, { as: 'AttackerBattles', through:UserBattleParticipation, foreignKey: { name: 'player1', allowNull: false }, otherKey: { name: 'battleId', allowNull: false }  });
```

2. You cannot define an association to get all participants of a battle because you have two different columns for a user.

If you you have a predefined list of users who are participating in a certain battle then you maybe should change your structure and add Participants (ParticipantId, BattleId, UserId) and use it in BattleParticipants (BattleId, ParticipantId1, ParticipantId2, other fields).

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand you answer. Are you saying I cannot make a table with one column referencing `Battle` and two other column each referencing a different `User` ? Is it a conception problem ?
`Battle` represents PvP battle, so each row of `UserBattleParticipation` must contains the result of `player1` vs `player2`, then maybe `player2` vs `player3`... but the combination `battleId,player1,player2` is unique.

Comment: Of cause you can make a table with two column referencing a different User. I mean you cannot get all participants at once by a single list of users in that case.